Twilio Conversation is not supporting React Native 0.71 +, SyntaxError
We use React Native to build our project, and your package "@twilio/conversations": "^2.6.0" is not compatible with "react-native": "0.75.4", it gives us SyntaxError in almost every your dist files.
.../node_modules/@twilio/conversations/dist/*.
**package.json**
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.75.4",
    "@twilio/conversations": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.75.4",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.75.4",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.75.4",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.75.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4"
}


error: SyntaxError:
node_modules/@twilio/conversations/dist/client.js: Missing semicolon. (1115:52)

  1113 | export { Client };
  1114 | //# sourceMappingURL=client.js.map
> 1115 | rts.Client.prototype, "handlePushNotification", null);
       |                                                     ^
  1116 | tslib_es6.__decorate([
  1117 |     declarativeTypeValidator.validateTypesAsync(declarativeTypeValidator.nonEmptyString),
  1118 |     tslib_es6.__metadata("design:type", Function),

We need to use library "@twilio/conversations" for conversations.

Roll back to a version that works and report this as a bug to their forums, assuming your data doesn't have an unterminated character as the cause of it.  Or if its critical its supported, you could consider switching to a front end that does support it.

Files in the /dist/ directory appear to be corrupted in version 2.6.0. Version 2.5.0 doesn't have this issue. I rolled back to 2.5.0 and problem solved.
